# Why does my prettier remove the ABIEncoderV2?

Tags: solidity, prettier

I'm using prettier to lint and fix my formatting of .sol files.

But for some reason, anytime it encounters `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;`, it transforms it to `pragma experimental ;`.

Why's it doing this?

My `.prettierrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  overrides: [
    {
      files: "*.sol",
      options: {
        bracketSpacing: false,
        printWidth: 145,
        tabWidth: 4,
        useTabs: false,
        singleQuote: false,
        explicitTypes: "always",
      },
    },
    {
      files: "*.ts",
      options: {
        printWidth: 145,
        semi: false,
        trailingComma: "es5",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```